# Use an environment variable in SyslogIdentifier in service file

Tags: rhel, services, systemd-unit

I'm working on a system running RHEL 7.9 and we're trying to use an environment variable to alter the `SyslogIdentifier` for the service. We've tried a number of options, but they all output exactly what's typed without doing a variable substitution. We've tried the following combinations:

```
SyslogIdentifier=app.${TRANSFER_DESC}
SyslogIdentifier=app.$TRANSFER_DESC
SyslogIdentifier=${TRANSFER_DESC}
SyslogIdentifier=$TRANSFER_DESC
```

They all show exactly what appears after the `=` in syslog, without substituting `TRANSFER_DESC`.

Comment: Here's a dumb idea, since I don't know how to do it properly: you could make a second copy of the service file (let's call it the template), and write a script using `awk` or `sed` to run what is basically a find-and-replace on the template and overwrite the main service file with the filled-out template. Then just invoke the script wherever/whenever it's appropriate (`cron` job perhaps?) and you've got yourself a horrible, hacked-together 'solution' :D Then in 5-10 years it'll break catastrophically and someone will be very, very confused what it was you were trying to do :P

Comment: After much reading, it was clear this couldn't be done in the way we intended, so we opted, instead, to have the application read the EV and prepend it in the log entries.